# Sonarqube - how to check for Logger or LoggerFactory in code

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to build a custom rule in Sonarqube using Java, that can catch the occurrence of this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

or the word `Logger` or `LogFactory` in the code.
Should I be using `visitLiteral()` for this?

Comment: This [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) will help you

Comment: This link talks about visitnode and visitmethod. My question isnt answered.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choice to achieve this, the simplest one being to write your custom rules extending the `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.IssuableSubscriptionVisitor`, following what is described in the [tutorial](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) (as perfectly pointed by @user7790438 in the comments of your question... you may have to adapt what is describe in it, but it gives you the basics), and register to `Tree.Kind.Identifier` nodes.

Then, once visiting all the Identifier nodes, simply cast the given nodes into 
`org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree`, and retrieve theirs `name()`. From there, you would be able to check if its called `Logger` or `LoggerFactory`.

Another approach could be to subscribe to `Tree.Kind.IMPORT` trees and simply inspect the qualified identifier. But usage of star-imports will make this not as efficient and won't allow you to find all occurences.

For your information, you can not visit literals, as you will end up visiting only literals of the language (Strings, integers, doubles, booleans, etc.), like the name of the method suggest...